# align button and li tag in a same horizontal line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align a `button` and `li` in a same line as the button.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j538zkwh/)

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray btn-sm">Log In</button>
     <ul>
         <li style="list-style-type:none;">
          <a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm" href="/password/recover">Forgot Password?
          </a>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: [see this](https://jsfiddle.net/j538zkwh/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add class **pull-left** to button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray btn-sm pull-left">Log In</button>

<ul>
 <li style="list-style-type:none;"><a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm" href="/password/recover">Forgot Password?</a></li>
```

Comment: exactly what I was trying to remember. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this two ways, `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` in this case I did the display property. Notice I also added two mockup classes for clarity, you can change them to whatever

[here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/batcave/j538zkwh/1/)

```
.btn__align {
  display: inline-block;
}

.ul__element {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did it with `pull-left` class on button. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through div or tables
https://jsfiddle.net/j538zkwh/5/

```
  <table >
            <td>
                <td>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray btn-sm">Log In</button> <a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm" href="/password/recover">Forgot Password? </a>
                 </td>
         </tr>
               </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did it with pull-left class on button. :) –

Answer (score 0):

try to add pull-left class at button will solve issue also find code posted below...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray btn-sm pull-left" >Log In</button>
<ul>
  <li style="list-style-type:none;">
    <a class="btn btn-gray btn-sm" href="/password/recover">Forgot Password?
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is Add this to your css Code

```
 display:inline-block;
```